# Insert Numpy array of float64 items into PostgreSQL as Binary

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql, numpy

I'm trying to insert Numpy array into PostgreSQL. Tried to do like this

```
def write_to_db(some_arr, some_txt):
""" insert a new array into the face_ar table """
    sql = """INSERT INTO test_db VALUES(%s,%s);"""
    conn = None
    try:
        params = config()
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql, (some_arr, some_txt))
        conn.commit()
        cur.close()

    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
```

Before it i created a table in my DB

```
create table test_db (encodings double precision[], link text);
```

Finally i got an error: "can't adapt type 'numpy.ndarray'"

I need to write Numpy array of 125 float64 items and small text like a link in each row. There will be a few millions of rows in my project. Just speed of reading and size of DB are important. As i got it is not possible to insert Numpy array directly, and need to convert it to another format. First idea i got was to convert it to Binary data and save it to DB, but i dont know how to do it and how to get it back from DB in Numpy array format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use pickle python for binary serialization/deserialization

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from pickle import dumps, loads
data=np.array([1,2,4,5,6])
dumped_data = dumps(data)
loaded_data = loads(dumped_data)
print(dumped_data)
print(loaded_data)
```

Comment: It is strange but pickle works much faster than np.save and np.loads.

Comment: I will try to make code faster with using msgpack-0.6.0 . Test showed that it decodes  2X faster than pickle, but it is not adapted for np arrays.

Comment: np.array has tolist method if you want to use msgpack-0.6.0 but it the same speed as pickle on with np.array on my computer.

Comment: % timeit dumps(encoding)
11.5 µs ± 489 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
% timeit loads(out)
5 µs ± 37.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
% timeit msgpack.packb(encoding, default=m.encode)
19.8 µs ± 581 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
% timeit msgpack.unpackb(x_enc, object_hook=m.decode)
3.62 µs ± 43.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Comment: with pickle.loading - 5µs ; with msgpack_numpy.unpack - 3.62 µs

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Vasyl Kushnir. This method started to work well and fast for reading data

```
import psycopg2
from config import config
import msgpack
import msgpack_numpy as m

def write_to_db(encoding, link):
""" insert a new array into the test1_db table """
    sql = """INSERT INTO test1_db VALUES(%s,%s);"""
    conn = None
    dumped_data = msgpack.packb(encoding, default=m.encode)
    try:
        params = config()
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql, (dumped_data, link))
        conn.commit()
        cur.close()

    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()

def read_from_db():
""" query data from the test1_db table """
    conn = None
    row = None
    try:
        params = config()
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT encodings, link FROM test1_db")
        print("The number of rows: ", cur.rowcount)
        row = cur.fetchone()
        cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
        encoding1, somelink = row
        return msgpack.unpackb(encoding1, object_hook=m.decode), somelink
```